# Is it a distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

Consider $F(x,y) = \mathbb{I}[x+y \geq 1] $ .

$\mathbb{I} $ denotes the indicator function . So , $F(x,y)$ is 1 iff $x+y \geq 1$ and $0$ otherwise .

Can we consider to be a bivariate distribution ? What are the necessary and sufficient conditions that are to be checked , and does this example satisfy all these requirements .

I am trying to understand bivariate distributions , so please try to bear with my (seemingly trivial ) questions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cumulative distribution function $F$ of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ satisfies the following properties:

1. $$\Delta_{a}^{b} F:= F(b_1,b_2)+F(a_1,a_2) - F(a_1,b_2) - F(b_1,a_2) \ge 0$$

where $a = (a_1,a_2)$, $b=(b_1,b_2)$ $\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $a_1 \le b_1$ and $a_2 \le b_2$.

2. (Continuity from the right)

$$ \lim_{x\to x_0^{+}} F(x,y) = F(x_0,y)$$

$$\lim_{y\to y_0^{+}} F(x,y) = F(x,y_0)$$

3. $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x,y) = \lim_{y\to-\infty}F(x,y) = 0$$
  4.

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty,\infty)}F(x,y) = 1$$

Comment: Does the example satisfy the fourth criterion ? I am unable to check that . Please consider adding it in the above nice explanation .

Comment: For that you're going to have to explain what $I[x+y \ge 1]$ means. Plz add that explanation in your question

Comment: please check edited question

Comment: I did check, yes. Yeah clearly $I$ satisfies the 4th criterion.

Comment: What is the meaning of the fourth condition . How do we calculate such "double" limits as $(x,y) \rightarrow \infty$ . Please explain .

Comment: $x$ and $y$ both are approaching infinity. Try doing this. What happens when you put $x=1000, y= 1000$? How about $x = 1,000,000$ , $y=1,000,000$? And so on. That's what we are doing. Looking at very very large values of both $x$ and $y$